# Java how do I format my output that's being written to text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to format my sql output through java and I've never formatted before in java. I've looked up some tutorials and I can't seem to find anything that helps me solve my problem. I'm going to cut majority of my code out so its not a lot, but heres what I've got.

```
    File file = new File("WO_SECURITY.doc");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, false);  
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    try {
    Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username1,password);

    stmt = con.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select usname as Name,                                   \r\n" + 
            "ususer as Username,                                      \r\n" + 
            "uswosecl as WO_SecurityLevel,                            \r\n" + 
            " aoOpid as Operation_ID,aoseclevel as Operation_Security,\r\n" + 
            "aomenu as Menu, aomenuitem as Tab, aoText as Description \r\n" + 
            "from cudtatet.xxpuser                                    \r\n" + 
            "join fmsusrfua.xxpAuOps on uswosecl >= aoseclevel        \r\n" + 
            "and aoseclevel >=0                                       \r\n" + 
            "WHERE ususer NOT IN ('*ALL','daffron')                   \r\n" + 
            "and aoAuOpID>=70000 and aoAuOpID < 80000                 \r\n" + 
            "order by usname,ususer                                   ");
  while (rs.next()) {   

      String name = rs.getString(1);
      String username = rs.getString(2);
      String woSeclevel = rs.getString(3);
      String menu = rs.getString(6);
      String tab = rs.getString(7);
      String Desc = rs.getString(8);

            if(!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }


            bw.write("Employee Name: " + name);             
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Employee username: " + username);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("WO Security Level:  " + woSeclevel);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Menu: " + menu + " > ");
            bw.write(tab + " > ");
            bw.write(Desc);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.newLine();
  }
```

I know its redundant and its not the output I'm wanting to be written onto my text file.
The current output I'm receiving on my text file is.
[image: output]

I would love to format it to display the employee name, username, and security level once as column headings if it could be and the menu, menu tabs, and menu descriptions underneath it.
My desired output:
[image: desired output]

If I could get some guidance on how to format my output to get my desired output that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think part of the solution is to:

- Move the output to separate methods (makes reading easier)
- Track the name that is being used.

So, for outputting, you might consider:

```
private void outputHeader(Writer out, String name, String username, String woSeclevel)
  throws IOException
{
    String hdr = String.format("Employee Name: %s  Username: %s  "
            + "WO Security Level %s%n",
            name, 
            username,
            woSeclevel);

    out.write(hdr);
}

private void ouputLine(Writer out, String menu, String tab, String desc)
    throws IOException
{
    String line = String.format("Menu: %s > %s > %s%n",
                                menu,
                                tab,
                                desc);
    out.write(line);
}
```

Then you could call it like:

```
String lastUsername = null;

while (rs.next) {
        String name = rs.getString(1);
        String username = rs.getString(2);
        String woSeclevel = rs.getString(3);
        String menu = rs.getString(6);
        String tab = rs.getString(7);
        String Desc = rs.getString(8);

        // when we change users (or if we haven't seen any user yet)
        // then output the header
        // if we have processed at least one user, then put space between
        // the last output and the new header
        if (lastUsername == null || ! lastUsername.equals(username)) {
            if (lastUsername != null) {
                bw.write("\n\n");
            }

            outputHeader(bw, name, username, woSeclevel);
        }
        outputLine(bw, menu, tab, Desc);

        // EDIT: this was wrong originally
        // we want to update the last seen username to be the username
        // of the current record; when the next record is retrieved, then
        // the comparison will output a new header if we have moved to
        // a different username. NOTE: assumes the records are properly
        // ordered
        lastUsername = username;
}
```

In this way, the header for the user would be emitted every time the username changed (which I presume is more unique name name itself), and the menu information for a user would be below the title.

Note that you probably want to order first by the username.

Comment: Thanks man. This helped me a lot and looks a lot cleaner too. Does return the output that I want because it is still repeating the Employee name, username, and WO Security Level. I will keep tweaking it and hopefully I will get my desired output.

Comment: There was a typo above; should be `lastUsername = username`. I've made the edit.

Comment: I saw the typo and I meant to correct it. When I change `! lastUsername.equals(username)` to `lastUsername.equals(username)` will return the results that I'm wanting, but it fails to change the username after every cycle. Meaning that it just prints the employee name,username, security level once, but then prints all the menu,tabs, and description without printing the next user.

Comment: I think it _should_ be `if (lastUsername == null || ! lastUsername.equals(username)) {`, because what we want is to output the header when we move to a new user (and, as I think I noted, the next user is defined by a new username). The typo was in the assignment of the variable `lastUsername` at the end of the loop -- it should be set to `lastUsername = username` (and not `lastUsername = name`).

Comment: Youre right Kevin. I had a simple typo in my code and it produced the results I was looking for. Thank you so much!